# Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'my_network'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having below error while running the docker-compose file.
I have created a bridge network with name my_network

`Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'my_network'`

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  webapp1:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: my_container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my_network
    volumes:
      - /home/ajay/nginx:/www/data
```

Comment: Did you create the network and want to attach the services to it?

Answer (score 3):

That seems docker-compose configuration issue, use below `docker-compose` file, it will create a network and then you can use the same network in the docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  webapp1:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: my_container
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Also Nginx port should be `80` inside the container if you did not modify the default configuration.